# Не обрабатывается OnTriggerEnter при смене родителя Unity3d, SetParent

Tags: c#, unity3d

Существует объект пуля и когда она является дочерним объектом ее спавнера, то при достижении нужного объекта функция OnTriggerEnter выполняется корректно и выводит лог, но если прописать строчку SetParen(null) для пули, то тригер больше не обрабатывается.
В чем может быть проблема?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SimpleBullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject Player;  
    

    private void Start()
    {
        transform.SetParent(null);
        // gameObject.transform.parent = null;
        Player = GameObject.Find("PlayerPers");


    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Debug.Log(transform.position);
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, Player.GetComponent<Control>().TargetPos.transform.position, 0.03f);
        Destroy(this.gameObject, 7f);
    }   

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Debug.Log(other.name);
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "EnemyBody")
        {
            //other.GetComponent<EnemyHp>().Hp();
            Debug.Log("Collison");
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: а для чего вообще делать ее(пулю) дочерней?

Comment: В любом случае если объект не является дочерним, то триггеры не работают. Если же оставить его дочерним, то все в порядке, но его движение зависит от родителя

Comment: Он дочерний Player'a? Приведи код генерации. Либо попробуй не устанавливать родителя изначально. Для чего это вообще?